# Find N element in sequence using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given the following table:

```
Sequence    Tag
-----       ----
1           a
2           a
3           a
88          a
100         a
1           b
7           b
88          b
101         b
```

I would like a query that returns the 4th in each sequence of tags (ordered by Tag, Sequence asc):

```
Tag         4thInSequence
-----       --------
a           88
b           101
```

What is the most efficient SQL I can use here? (Note: SQL Server 2008 tricks are allowed)

Comment: How many elements per tag (on average)? What indexes can we assume?

Comment: Can you use linq? That would make it very straight forward. Alternatively, you could construct the query in Linq, then capture the SQL output.

Comment: @Martin, you can assume both sequence / tag and tag / sequence indexes. Avg of about 400 rows per tag.

Comment: @cofiem I much prefer a SQL only solution, its much easier to deploy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WITH Enumerated AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY Sequence) AS RN 
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT * FROM Enumerated WHERE RN = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, this is going to help make your user page less ugly, I'm getting the historic dates your badges were assigned

Comment: Yes I doubt that this will be bettered.

Comment: ahh big relief, your bronze tag badges now show up in the order they were assigned :)